# How to search a pattern like pattern using grep only?

Tags: grep

I am searching list of names with pattern "japconfig".There are many files inside one directory. Those files contain names like ixdf_japconfig_FZ.txt,
ixdf_japconfig_AB.txt, ixdf_japconfig_RK.txt, ixdf_japconfig_DK.txt, ixdf_japconfig_LY.txt. But I don't know what are the names present after japconfig word. I need to list down all such names. Also my files contain ixdf_dbconfig.txt, but I don't want to print ixdf_dbconfig.txt in the output.

Each of my file contains one ixdf_japconfig_*.txt and ixdf_dbconfig.txt where * can be FZ,AB,RK,DK,LY. I can achieve my desired result by using grep and then awk to cut the columns.But I don't want to use AWK or other command. I want to achive using grep only.

I need to print below names.

```
ixdf_japconfig_FZ.txt
ixdf_japconfig_AB.txt
ixdf_japconfig_RK.txt
ixdf_japconfig_DK.txt
ixdf_japconfig_LY.txt
```

I don't want to print ixdf_dbconfig.txt.

When I tried using "grep -oh "ixdf_japconfig.*.txt" *.dat" command, I am getting below output.

```
ixdf_japconfig_FZ.txt  ixdf_dbconfig.txt
ixdf_japconfig_AB.txt  ixdf_dbconfig.txt
ixdf_japconfig_RK.txt  ixdf_dbconfig.txt
ixdf_japconfig_DK.txt  ixdf_dbconfig.txt
ixdf_japconfig_LY.txt  ixdf_dbconfig.txt
```

where first column is my desired column. But I don't want to print second column. How can I change my code to print only first column?

Comment: Why tag the question with sed, awk, and vi if you `want to achive using grep only.`? You might want to also state WHY it's got to be a grep solution even if other tools might be more appropriate.

Comment: Hi, I am new to stack overflow, so I just tagged all, so that everybody can have a view to my Qs. I need to know by if by using grep and regular expression can I achieve my desired result or not. If I can achieve with grep only ,then why would I go for any other command.I want to make my command simple by using regular expression not any other command.

Comment: Don't add irrelevant tags "so that everybody can have a view". Not everyone is interested in grep questions.

Comment: Hi Vicky. Some people would call this "tag spamming" - using irrelevant tags deliberately in order to increase a question's readership. Since this harms the search system, you may receive downvotes for this - it is best avoided `:-)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for informing me. I am completely unaware of this. I joined for learning unix in depth. If you can guide me well, I can learn faster.

Comment: @vicky wrt `If I can achieve with grep only ,then why would I go for any other command` - the answer is that the solution might be simpler, faster, more robust, and/or more portable with some other tool. You can do less with grep than you can with sed or awk but that doesn't mean that a grep solution will be the simplest for every problem. Try for example greping for a, b, c, and d in any order. You need 4 calls to grep (`grep a | grep b | grep c | grep d`) vs one call to awk (`awk '/a/ && /b/ && /c/ && /d/`). Now try to express `awk '/a/ && (/b/ || /c/) && !(/b/ && /c/)'` using `grep`.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -oh ixdf_japconfig_...txt *.dat
```

(Your `.*.` was matching most of the line.)

Comment: Hi Beta, there's a typo error. I was trying with "grep -oh "ixdf_japconfig.*\.txt" *.dat " command. I m escaping . character before txt.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my Qs.I am getting desired output now.By the way can u tell me when  double quote is required and when it's not. I am confused with lots of syntaxes from internet. Can you send me good websites to refer for grep using regular expressions.

Comment: @vickybindass: There is a good tutorial on quotes [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html). Read my answer again; your `.*.` was matching most of the line.

Comment: I have below names inside files. 
    ixdf_japconfig_FZ.txt
    ixdf_japconfig_AB.txt
    ixdf_japconfig_RK.txt
    ixdf_japconfig_DK.txt
    ixdf_japconfig_LY.txt.
    ixdf_japconfig_FZKR.txt
    ixdf_japconfig_AB.txt
    ixdf_japconfig_RKB.txt
    ixdf_japconfig_DK.txt
    ixdf_japconfig_L.txt How to print all these names?

Comment: @vickybindass: One question per question, please, and don't delete your questions after I answer them. Search for "grep regex", the solution isn't hard to find.